# iOS 6/7: How Managing 2 Nested Modal Dialog in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, modal-dialog, modalviewcontroller

I have to add two modal dialogs right after the login window in my app before to go to the default tabViewContrller in my app. I have provided two modal dialogs in Storyborad and I did a quick testing to bring two modal dialogs one after another but none it's a perfect way to handle it.

I tried this in my **first** modal dialog when user tried to dismiss the current modal and has to go to second modal dialog:

```
-(IBAction)continueAction1:(id)sender{


  UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle: nil];
  ModalViewController_alert *modalViewController = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"second_modal_alert"];
  [modalViewController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
  [modalViewController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
  [self presentViewController:modalViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(self.view.superview.center.x - 200,self.view.superview.center.y + 100 -100,400,300);
modalViewController.view.superview.frame = frame;

 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];//dismiss the first modal doesn't dispose it ??

}
```

and in the second modal dialog when user click on "Continue" button I did this in the class

```
-(IBAction)continueAction2:(id)sender{
  FFAppDelegate *appDelegate = (FFAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate doSomeExtensiveTaskInAThread_Cleanup];


   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];//dismiss second one.
```

}

I also tried to use segue instead of first continueAction1 but don't know why after dismissing second dialog it shows me the first dialog for a moment before it goes to default tabViewController in the app(based on the extensive task in a thread as commented in my code).

Can someone show me a good approach to bring two modal dialog right after each other? what is wrong in my approach?

Comment: I don't want to discourage you but showing a second modal dialog after a first one is VERY strange user interaction pattern. It is not what users are expecting, it is confusing. Perhaps your user of "modal dialog" phrase is not correct though. Could you please provide screenshots for two screens you describe so that we can have a better understanding of what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I think you should just present a navigation view controller in a modal fashion, push your separate dialogs onto the navigation view controller and then dismiss the navigation controller after the second view.

Comment: It sounds like you may be trying to create something like an installation wizard user experience?  Keep in mind that on an iPad, a popover view can be dismissed by tapping anywhere outside the view, so immediately displaying another dialog would seem unusual / surprising.  The Human Interface Guidelines suggest that you don't ask the user to log in before needed.  Do you really need these modal dialogs up-front?

Comment: Nils, you're correct that a navigation view controller is a better way to implement - I was going to suggest it but I am not sure if the overall approach is correct.

Comment: I know it's not a encouraging approach to represent two modal dialogs but my client asked me to show two pieces of important info in two steps. I'm free to choose the right way to to represent this.I tried segue with modal style to push the second modal in navigation but It was not able to have the second dialog in different size(it appears as the same size of previous on),second problem: when dismissing second dialog, it shows first dialog for seconds before continue to main window in app(as I guess it's a right behavior for using navigation). Please correct me if I'm wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you chain modal presentations together, you can dismiss them all at once by having the controller that did the original presentation call dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:. So in, continueAction1, don't dismiss the first modal, just present the second one. In continueAction2, reference the first controller with self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController to do the dismissal:

```
[self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

You can also do this with modal segues, in which case you can use an unwind segue in the last controller to go back to wherever you want, no matter how many modal segues were chained together.

Comment: So, I don't need to dismiss the second modal dialog in continueAction2?

Comment: @Cam, no, if you have the original controller do the dismissal, both modal controllers will be dismissed.

Comment: is anyway to hide the first modal when I show the second modal? right now, the only way to hide the old one, I have to make the second dialog as big as old one(to cover that)?

Comment: @Cam, well normally a modal does take up the whole view (it doesn't actually cover it, because there's no other view in the window's hierarchy). If your modal doesn't cover the whole view, what do you want to see in the areas where it isn't?